# Problems running the program on another machine

Tags: c#, dependencies

I'm having trouble running the program on another machine. It returns an error that is missing some dll. So that all DLLs are in the program folder. I selected all dependencies and put "copy always" and also created a setup project, yet it still returning error.

```
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: program.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.1.0
  Problem Signature 03: 581b1c83
  Problem Signature 04: Program
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.1.0
  Problem Signature 06: 581b1c83
  Problem Signature 07: c1
  Problem Signature 08: 5
  Problem Signature 09: System.DllNotFoundException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.2
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the `CopyLocal=true` in your project.

> The Copy Local property determines whether a reference is copied to the local bin path. At run time, a reference must exist in either the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) or the output path of the project. If this property is set to true, the reference is copied to the output path of the project at run time.

You could refer to this solution, too.
[How can I debug System.DllNotFoundException when missing DLL is not reported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021966/how-can-i-debug-system-dllnotfoundexception-when-missing-dll-is-not-reported)

Comment: Hi. Is it possible that some of the dlls your are using are COM dlls that need to be registered? Or maybe they are .NET assemblies that need to be in the GAC? Is the proyect compiled in anycpu, x86 or x64 and so are the dlls?